# Why my initial react native app is too big (>500mb)

Tags: ios, react-native, build

I created empty react native project.

Open xCode -> choose Any IOS device -> product/click archive -> build app

.app file size >500mb
(interesting that simulator .app file 20mb)

[image]

Comment: I solved my problem by disabling `hermes` in ios/Podfile 

:hermes_enabled => false